# Android TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, Not able to focus on any part of the display

Tags: android

I have an app that runs on touch screens like a tablet and also TVs (ex: Fire TV).

My app needs to display a button on top of all apps/activities and when this button is clicked, a certain action needs to be performed.

I have the following:

```
var button = Button(this)
var windowManager = getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
button.text = "HOME"

button?.setOnClickListener {
// do something
}

val params = WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
)

params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM or Gravity.END
windowManager?.addView(button, params)
```

At first, I had issue on touch screen where no matter when I click on the window, the click events were going to the above button window. This resolved by adding `FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL`.

Now on TVs, I have the following layout (Think of it like Fire TV home page)
[image: TV layout]

So the problem is, I couldn't change focus from the button. Pressing on D-pad does nothing. It always focused on the button. I can't use `FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE` because that completely prevents the button from gaining focus on remote navigation.

What I want is to be able to navigate from other UI elements to this HOME button and also navigate away from HOME button